# Geocoding two addresses in one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I want to geocode two addresses in one model, ie. a Journey has a StartAddress and EndAddress.
Thus,
I have three attributes on my model:
StartAddress
start_longtitude
start_lattitude
EndAddress
end_longtitude
end_lattitude

How can I geocode it so that I can call the nearbys function to find i) Journeys that start nearby a given journey and ii) journeys that end nearby a particular journey?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent update that allows this.
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/pull/692

Geocode the model with your own geocoding function, then in the near function specify the alternate attrbitutes you want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem and solution are expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482230/geocoder-to-work-with-two-addresses) very well.

Add the following `before_save` and corresponding method to your model in order to solve the problem. Don't forget to repeat part of the code for the second location (maybe destination):

```
before_save :geocode_endpoints

  private
  #To enable Geocoder to works with multiple locations
  def geocode_endpoints
    if from_changed?
      geocoded = Geocoder.search(loc1).first
      if geocoded
        self.latitude = geocoded.latitude
        self.longitude = geocoded.longitude
      end
    end
    # Repeat for destination
        if to_changed?
      geocoded = Geocoder.search(loc2).first
      if geocoded
        self.latitude2 = geocoded.latitude
        self.longitude2 = geocoded.longitude
      end
    end
  end
```