# Geocoder to work with two addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

rails 4.1.3 application with Geocoder gem has the following attributes on a model

```
  t.decimal :origin_lon, :precision => 15, :scale => 10
  t.decimal :origin_lat, :precision => 15, :scale => 10
  t.point :origin_lonlat, :srid => 3857
  t.decimal :destination_lon, :precision => 15, :scale => 10
  t.decimal :destination_lat, :precision => 15, :scale => 10
  t.point :destination_lonlat, :srid => 3857
```

The model is defined with

```
geocoded_by :origin, :latitude  => :origin_lat, :longitude => :origin_lon
geocoded_by :destination, :latitude  => :destination_lat, :longitude => :destination_lon
```

However if I run in the console:

```
Circuit.create(origin: 'avenue des Champs-Élysées, 90 Paris', destination: 'Place Mariejol, Antibes')
```

*don't look it up, it's the Picasso Museum...*
only destination data is being populated. If the order of the `geocoded_by` instructions are inverted and the server is re-started, then the origin data is being populated. So clearly only one call for `geocoded_by` is possible under this syntax.

What syntax allows for the two simultaneous searches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `geocoded_by` [calls `geocoder_init`](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/v1.2.13/lib/geocoder/models/active_record.rb#L12), which only contains [one set of options](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/v1.2.13/lib/geocoder/models/base.rb#L35), so `geocoded_by :destination` clobbers `geocoded_by :origin`.

```
def geocoder_init(options)
  unless defined?(@geocoder_options)
    @geocoder_options = {}
    require "geocoder/stores/#{geocoder_file_name}"
    include Geocoder::Store.const_get(geocoder_module_name)
  end
  @geocoder_options.merge! options
end
```

You can write your own ActiveRecord hook to geocode both:

```
class Circuit < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :geocode_endpoints

  private

  def geocode_endpoints
    if origin_changed?
      geocoded = Geocoder.search(origin).first
      if geocoded
        self.origin_lat = geocoded.latitude
        self.origin_lon = geocoded.longitude
      end
    end
    # Repeat for destination
  end
end
```

Take a look at the [`geocode` method](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/v1.2.13/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb#L270-L284) to see how the gem does it, what kind of errors, it handles. etc. Unfortunately, we can't use [`do_lookup`](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/v1.2.13/lib/geocoder/stores/base.rb#L83) because that relies on the configured options instead of accepting parameters.

Comment: OK. clear; the reference to the gem file is useful as well!